# Drupal 7 on browser close automatic logout

Tags: session, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7.

drupal?q=user

when we logged in , after that we close browser & reopen browser again then it should ask for login.

But it remains logged in

I have used session expire module & also set

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);   in sites/default/settings.php

but it didn't work anyone have solve?

Answer (score 1):

You should set this in your settings.php

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 0);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
```

But in FireFox session_cookies keep alive till the browser compeletly closed,(not terminate by closing only drupal tabs ) :(

Answer (score 0):

Session Expire module create a instance on a table called session, that's why if you change session cookie on setting.php nothing happen... the only way to resolve it is creating an ajax that call the user/logout page on browser clousure.

I am trying to get this working without success, if you got finally the solution can you share with me, please!

see this link to get more information: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/02/22/jquery-javascript-capture-the-browser-or-tab-closed-event/